# Detecting or correcting unexpected termination with Python and Com

Tags: python, windows, com, win32com

I'm using win32com to convert a large number of PPT and PPTX files to PDF.  I'm using the same process but with Word and Excel to convert DOC, DOCX, XLS, and XLSX files to PDF.

Almost everything seems to run smoothly apart from an intermittent crash when converting Powerpoint.  When the crash happens a window pops-up saying "Power point has stopped working"

The windows error has this info:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: POWERPNT.EXE
  Application Version:  14.0.7162.5000
  Application Timestamp:    561e73e5
  Fault Module Name:    ppcore.dll
  Fault Module Version: 14.0.7171.5000
  Fault Module Timestamp:   57621d53
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0001026d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.274.10
  Locale ID:    3081

Additional information about the problem:
  LCID: 1033
  skulcid:  1033
```

which is hardly informative, and the code I'm using is this:

```
officeapp = client.DispatchEx("PowerPoint.Application")
doc = officeapp.Presentations.Open(source_file,ReadOnly=True,WithWindow=False)
doc.SaveAs(target_file, FileFormat=32)
doc.Close()
officeapp.Quit()
```

When the crash occurs it effectively freezes the batch process, and I need to keep checking to see if the process is still running.  This is obviously not ideal.  Any ideas on how I could

a) Stop the crash
b) Detect the error and close the windows pop-up